# Ruby on Rails Web application just freezes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my environment

Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 2.3.11
Sql Server 2008 DB

BACKGROUND:
I have a web site which is basically a mapping application. Apart from the environment I described above there are a few other component that this web site uses

1. GDAL (it is a command line application that is called from one of the controllers to find elevation upon an ajax request)
2. Geoserver : Javascript uses GML data from this

Here is my list of Gems:

actionmailer (2.3.11)
actionpack (2.3.11)
activerecord (2.3.11)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (2.3.16)
activeresource (2.3.11)
activesupport (2.3.14, 2.3.11)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mingw32)
mongrel_output_compression (0.1.0)
rack (1.1.2)
rails (2.3.11)
rake (0.9.2)
ruby-odbc (0.99994)

As the list shows I am using Mongrel behind an Apache server.

PROBLEM:
The web server/website just freezes after random time (usually in around 2 to 3 hours). The logs show nothing strange. I am clueless why this happens. The site runs fine again when i restart the mongrel server. IT used to work fine, but over time some where in the development the bug crept in. Going back and checking the versions in SVN seems useless because it might have come in quite some time back.

My unit, functional and integration test cases pass fine too.

Any one has faced the same problem or have ideas what may be happening? All suggestions are welcome so i can check them out.

Thanks
Shaunak.

Comment: are you sure the server is not trashing? a little swap usage under heavy load will freeze everything for some time.

Comment: SQL Server database connection might be the culprit.  It hangs for me on the first load a Rails app into RAM.

Comment: @jackdoe : the site is still under development and doesnt have live users. so no heavy usage. What exactly do you mean by swap usage?

Comment: @Teddy: I checked that and no SQL server has been running fine from the day one and this problem came up later. SQL Server appears to be running smoothly for me.

Comment: @Shaunak http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging but if it is still in development i doubt that that will be the issue (ofc if you are not eating all the memory in your app)

Comment: Yup. thanks. Is there any way i can profile my mongrel server on windows to see what exactly is causing the crash? There is nothing in the rails log files.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you use gdb to attach to the mongrel process and figure out what it is doing.  If you rather use a ruby tool to do that, you can use gdb.rb (https://github.com/tmm1/gdb.rb).  I am assuming that you are running on a linux type of server.

Comment: I am in windows environment because of client restrictions. Can you suggest a alternative on windows environment to do the same? thanks!